# Magento 2 Taxes are still not figuring correctly

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping-methods, tax

> Subtotal   : $81.73
>
> Shipping & Handling  $10.55
>
> So currently tax is calculated on $81.73 but it needs to be calculated
>   on (81.73+10.55) = $92.28. Right?

***This is my tax setting***

[image]

Thanks is advance

**Dose anyone know how this will happen.**

Comment: Plz share admin settings from `Sales > Tax`

Comment: Plz check my answer list

Comment: You will require to add Tax Class for Shipping. It is the first field in your configuration and its set to "None", uncheck the box and select your applicable tax class for shipping rates, the taxes will be applied on shipping rates too.

Comment: hi this is my cart total https://prnt.sc/r6v2p3